# I cannot install Xcuitest on mac after running this command: "appium driver install xcuitest" in terminal

Tags: automation, appium, xcuitest

✖ Installing 'xcuitest' using NPM install spec 'appium-xcuitest-driver'
Error: ✖ Encountered an error when installing package: npm command 'install --save-dev --omit=peer --save-exact --global-style --no-package-lock appium-xcuitest-driver --json' failed with code 1.

STDOUT:
{
"error": {
"code": "EACCES",
"summary": "\nYour cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in\nprevious versions of npm which has since been addressed.\n\nTo permanently fix this problem, please run:\n  sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/USERNAME/.npm"",
"detail": ""
}
}

STDERR:
npm WARN config global-style This option has been deprecated in favor of `--install-strategy=shallow`
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/26/ce/363bc520dd5a50689c636f2f5a6c1804d7844b9b622bec5f6f30c7623ded
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/USERNAME/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_logs/2023-06-15T18_51_39_343Z-debug-0.log

Right now I have no driver installed:
✔ Listing available drivers

- uiautomator2 [not installed]
- xcuitest [not installed]
- mac2 [not installed]
- espresso [not installed]
- safari [not installed]
- gecko [not installed]
- chromium [not installed]
  I'm trying to install xcuitest and uiautomator2 drivers.
  When I run the above command for uiautomator2, I got the same output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Clear appium folder before install:

```
 rm -rf ~/.appium
```

More information about similar issue:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/18006